# jquery - find first div containing an empty input

Tags: jquery, selector

Using jquery, how can I find the first div that contains an input with no value?

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" value="12">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" value="13">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text">
</div>

$('.field input').filter('text[value=""]').parent().addClass('first_empty')
```

Comment: $('div.field input') .filter('input:text[value=""]') .filter(':first') .parent().css('background-color', 'green');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were so close. Add the element to the attribute selector, or `':text[value=""]'` will work as well. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/KeAZ4/1/)

```
 $('.field :input').filter('input:text[value=""]')
                   .parent(':first')
                   .addClass('first_empty');
```

Comment: in this demo it actually selects all divs that have empty inputs, not just the first one

Comment: Yeah, oversight on my part. Fixed!

Comment: @alpacalips Is there some way to extend this check to consider empty whitespaces too? I mean, selecting those inputs also which have only whitespaces in the value?

Answer (score 3):

Selectors won't work, because a user typing input affects the `value` **property**, NOT the `value` attribute.

You will need something like this (I'm writing this in plain JS because I don't use jQuery):

```
function findFirstEmptyInput() {
    var qsa = document.querySelectorAll(".field input"), l = qsa.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        if( qsa[i].value == '') return qsa[i];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between the attribute and property.

Comment: I got +5 the other day for providing a CSS solution instead of using jQuery. Please revise your view on life.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.field > input:text[value=""]').parent().addClass('first_empty');
```